# Cakephp admin and user login simultaneously not working correctly

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

I have two type of users in my website.
1.User (Frontend)
2.Admin (Backend)

I used cakephp auth component for login both type of user.
my problem is that when i login using one type of users i will automatically login to other type of user for example i login as user from frontend but when i refresh backed it will show me logedin and same problem with admin type of user.

Below are my auth Code separate for admin and user.

This is AppController.php file in app/Controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->Auth->user()){
    $this->set('logged_in', true);
    }else{
    $this->set('logged_in', false);
    }
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.is_active' => '1');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'signin','plugin' => 'umgmt');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'signin','plugin' => 'umgmt');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index','plugin' => false);

    }
```

This is my admin plugin controller code

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Admin',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ),
                     'scope'=>array('Admin.is_active' => 1)
                )
            )
        )
    );


public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard');

}
```

I am using cakephp 2.4.1

Please help me

Comment: where is login action ?

Comment: Moyed Ansari i have update code above for admin login action

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Firstly a quick note, you do not need to set your `logged_in` and `out` variables as the AuthComponent provides this functionality with the `AuthComponent::loggedIn()` method.

Secondly you have not set your type of Auth. As per the book, it's usually wise to use `Controller` so that you can manage your authentication on a per action basis.

So you need to update your component configuration or your `beforeFilter()` to include the type of authorization.

`$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');`

Then you can use the `isAuthorized()` method in your `AppController` to check the roles of your users based on the routing prefix being used.

All of this implementation is [covered in the Cake book in the chapter on Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html).

Comment: DavidYell , is this posible to use Cake AuthComponent for two type of users(admin,user) login in same browser simultaneously ? actually the problem is that ."When i login as a normal user in frontend using Auth i will automatically logged in as a admin in backend and show mw dashboard". i hope you can help me to solve my problem Thanks for you reply i tried $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller'); in before filter but this things not stoping simultaneously login user.